# Can I create an object for Interface?

Tags: java, class, oop, instance

Is it possible to create an object for an interface?  If yes, how is it done?
According to my view the following code says that we can:

```java
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    // some implementation
}
```

Comment: Related concept: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994009/can-we-create-object-of-abstract-class

Answer (score 20):

This is not creating the instance of Interface, it is creating a class that implements interface. So when you write:

```java
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

You are actually a creating a class that is implementing the Runnable interface.
You need to follow all rules here, here, we are overriding the run method for `Runnable`. There is similar thing for abstract class also. We can test using an example:

```java
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("abstract class");
    }
}
```

and another class i.e. `TestClass`:

```java
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractClass abstractClass = new AbstractClass() {
            public void someMethod() {
                System.out.println("concrete class method");
            }
        };
        abstractClass.someMethod();
    }
}
```

This will create the instance of a subclass in which we are overriding `someMethod()`;
This program prints:

```
concrete class method
```

This proves we are creating the instance of subclass.

Answer (score 13):

You can't instantiate an interface directly, but you can instantiate a class that implements that interface:

```
public class RunClass implements Runnable {
    // Class implementation
}

Runnable r = new RunClass();
```

This is basically the same as what you're doing inline. The brackets after new Runnable() will contain your implementation inline.

Comment: This is a bit misleading. The OP's question uses anonymous class syntax, which is probably the point.

Answer (score 9):

You can create an anonymous inner class:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
};
```

Therefore you create a new `class` which implements the given `interface`.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible to creating object for an interface?

No. The code you've shown creates an object from an *anonymous class*, which implements the interface. Under the covers, the JVM actually creates a class implementing the interface, and then creates an instance of that class.

---

The "anonymous" class generated *will* actually have a name, based on the name of the class in which this code appears, for instance `YourClass$1` or similar. E.g.:

```
public class AnonymousName {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            }
        };

        System.out.println(r.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

...outputs

```
AnonymousName$1
```

(At least on Oracle's JVM; I don't know if the naming convention is in the JLS or if it's JVM-specific behavior.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's my understanding.

An interface

```
public Interface SomeInterface{
}
```

You can declare an Object for an interface.

```
SomeInterface anObject;
```

You cannot instantiate this object directly using this interface. 
However, let's say you have a class that implements this interface.

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {}
```

Then you can do this,

```
anObject = new someClass();
```

(This is conceptually of course (like pseudocode) actual code may vary depending on your classes and access modifiers etc.)

I'll update as to why exactly we are doing this/what the point is as soon as I find out.

Note: Some of this has been mentioned in above answers, just want the OP to know this whole thing too.

Comment: This is done to achieve abstraction, a concept to hide the details of the actual implementation while giving the output. 
Eg: There can  be multiple instances created but with only single reference of the interface--
anObject1 = new FirstClass();
anObject2 = new SecondClass();
anObject3 = new ThirdClass();

corresponding to the references, the corresponding methods in the 3 classes will be triggered.

Purpose ? 

The purpose of using anObject as a reference variable is because at runtime, we dont know which instance will be created.. This is done to achieve loose coupling .

Answer (score 0):

we can not instatiate the interface (since do not have constructor).

Comment: I don't think so Rais. May be you could solve his problem. It looks complete answer to me.

Comment: your answer is correct. I guess suitable place is comment and not answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is an  [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

it’s creating an instance of a new, anonymous,implementer of Runnable class.

**Because an anonymous class definition is an expression, it must be part of a statement.**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create Object of interface, but you can create Object of class that is **extends** interface.

Like if you like to create an Object of `Interface Laptop` and declare method `void writeCode()` and implement this method in class `class Development` you can use concept of anonymous inner class concept.

now you can create object of anonymous inner class object reference or type of `Interface Laptop`

```
public interface Laptop {
    public abstract void writeCode();
}
```

```
public class Developer implements Laptop{
    public void writeCode() {
        System.out.println("In developer Class");
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Laptop lap = new Laptop() {
            @Override
            public void writeCode() {
                System.out.println("In new Method");
            }
        };

        lap.writeCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no need for the `Developer` class in posted code at all - an anonymous class does not need another non-anonymous class... BTW the question is 10 years old!