# Need clarification about creating object, function and their arguments

Tags: java, android

I am learning android development. And I do have basic newbie understanding about this. And I am having trouble to understand these kinds of code: -

example 1.

```
requestPublishPermissionsButton.addListener(new InputListener() {

        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            loginWithPublishPermissions();
        }

    });
```

example 2.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

I know that in both examples there are creations of new objects using InputListner class (in example 1) and Handler class (in example 2) with no argument passing. But **what's between "{" "}", is it behaviour or constructor of class or something else**?

Comment: I highly recommend getting yourself familiar with Java before learning Android. Learning how to walk makes it easier to learn how to run

Comment: ^ I second that motion. SO is not to be used for learning programming basics.

Comment: ok, i will. thanks.

Comment: agree with @Dummy 1. Solid background in OOP and Java. 2. Better control what-if can (how works listeners etc) be found in GUI like Swing or  SWT - android have many, many hidden (at first sight) behaviours

Answer (score 0):

It is an interface.

Here is a [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), so you can learn more about them.

Comment: I think I am wrong at the first place. Referring to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400664/can-i-create-object-for-interface There is no object creation but a class creation using the interface Handler (in eg. 2). Am I getting it right?

Comment: Yes, thats basically it. Classes implement interfaces. You could also create a class that implements this interface and pass it in there like a argument, it would work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

That's a shorthand notation for creating a class (to be used only in this place) and an instance of that class at the same time.

Let's take example 2 (similar for example 1).

Handler is a class having at least one method `public void handleMessage(Message msg)` (or an interface requiring this one method).

The example does two things:

- At compile time it creates an anonymous class extending the Handler class (or implementing the Handler interface) and providing the given implementation of the `handleMessage()` method.
- At runtime it creates an instance of this anonymous class.

Remarks

You prabably want to change the body of the `handleMessage()` method. If the implementation just calls `super.handleMessage(msg)`, the whole construct is nonsense because the anonymous class shows exactly the same behaviour as the superclass, so a simple `Handler Handler = new Handler();` does exactly the same.