# Since List is an interface and how we are creating instance without any anonymous class

Tags: java, collections

In java collections, Since List is an interface and how the "new" keyword is used to declare it without any anonymous class.

Please explain how the following line works.
List listTry= new ArrayList();

How the instance is created for ArrayList interface.

Comment: `ArrayList` is a class, not an interface

Answer (score 0):

`List listTry= new ArrayList();`

This line assign an ArrayList object into List reference.

ArrayList is a child class of List, and able to create object.

Comment: I got an answer thanks.         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400664/can-i-create-object-for-interface