# Lambda expression return type in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm learning about Lambda in Java and I try to understand it. For example I have this following code:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Square 
{ 
    int calculate(int x); 
} 

class Test 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        int a = 5; 

        Square s = (int x) -> x*x; 

        int ans = s.calculate(a); 
        System.out.println(ans); 
    } 
}
```

I do not understand this statement `Square s = (int x) -> x*x;` I see that `s` is a reference variable of type `Square`. But I don't understand what exactly is this `(int x) -> x*x`. Is this a method definition? What is the return type of this method? I think it should be `int` because the return type of `calculate` method is `int`. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: *"what exactly is this `(int x) -> x*x`"* It's a **lambda expression**, and it's curious that you need to ask, since your question title uses the term, and you say you're already learning about them. In this case, it's the same as `x -> x*x`, but with the type of the lambda parameter explicitly given.

Answer (score 5):

Your lambda expression can be replaced by anonymous class :

```
Square s = new Square() {
    @Override
    public int calculate(int x) {
        return x * x;
    }
};
```

So `(int x) -> x*x` is just implementation of `calculate` method that takes `int` argument and return `int` value. By the way it is not necessary to specify parameter type. You can do like :

```
Square s = x -> x*x;
```

Now you have object of type `Square` and you can call the `calculate` method that was defined before in lambda expression:

```
int squared = s.calculate(5);
```

Comment: Thank for reply, but is it possible that s which is a reference variable of type Square to point to an int value?

Comment: @gaby No, because `s` must point to an object of type `Square`. When you write `(int x) -> x*x`, the compiler will create an object of type `Square` for you, which implements the `calculate` method using that lambda expression.

Comment: Thank you Andreas! But how is possible to return an object of type Square? Square is an interface and I know that you cannot create object of an interface.

Comment: @gaby You can't create an instance of interface, but you can create an anonymous class that implements this interface. See here for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400664/can-i-create-object-for-interface

Comment: @Ruslan This is not true, lambda do not create an anonymous class, you can look in the bin folder to see that there is no anonymous class created when you are using lambda.

Comment: @gaby You are rigth. To be precise lambda expressions use [*invoke dynamic*](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood) call and they are stored in the same file

Answer (score 1):

It's lambda syntax.   It's syntactic sugar for ...

```
Square s = new Square ()
   {
   @Override
   public int calculate (int x)
      {
      return x*x;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Not really, since a lambda expression doesn't create an anonymous class.

Comment: @Andreas, well it's not CALLED an anonymous class, but it's essentially the same thing, other than slightly different scoping rules.  Certainly a class gets created, and it's anonymous.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem An anonymous class does *not* get created by the compiler for a lambda expression. Unlike a real anonymous class, you don't get a new `.class` file. The *body* of the lambda expression is compiled into a hidden (private, synthetic) method, e.g. named `lambda$1`, on the class containing the lambda, and the lambda expression is then compiled into a method reference to that method.

Answer (score 1):

A lambda can also be thought of as a quick way to define (or redefine) an abstract function. (They call it syntactic sugar.) So you could write it like this, also:

```
Square s; 
s = x -> x*x; 
System.out.println (s.calculate(5)); // 25
```

What's happening there is you're filling in the blanks of the function declaration. The argument is 'x' and the body of the function (aka method in Java) is 'return x*x'.

Consider that you could do this next, also: (Note addition of curly braces to support a multi-line block. The return is explicitly declared, then. Also, the input type can be explicitly declared, too -- visual indicator to reference overloading.)

```
s = (int x) -> { return x*x*x ; } ; // brackets allow multi-line operations
System.out.println (s.calculate(2)); // 8
```

So, there is the capacity to dynamically reassign new operations to an abstract method in a very shorthand mechanism.

Consider that the interface could also define something like this:

```
int calculate(String x); // note change in argument type -- overloading
```

At that point you could do something like this: (Type of s is a String.)

```
s = s -> { return s.length()*2 ; } ; 
System.out.println (s.calculate("It!")); // 6
```

Bottom line is that lambdas provide an incredibly flexible and shorthand method to define and redefine methods on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

The calculate method in your Square interface accepts an int and returns an int, but there is no implementation of the logic how to calculate the return value as it has no method body { ....... }like other methods you may know.

So the snippet that you have doesn't point to an int but implements the logic ( how to calculate). It might be misleading with the name Square but following expressions are valid:

```
  Square s = (int x) -> x*x; // your example
  Square s1 = (int x) -> x*x*x;    // takes an int x and returns the cube of x
  Square s2 = (int x) -> x+42; // takes an int x and returns x+42
  Square s3 = (int x) -> x%2; // takes an int and returns 0 if x is even 1 otherwise
```